# Use external table redshift spectrum defined in glue data catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a table defined in Glue data catalog that I can query using Athena. As there is some data in the table that I want to use with other Redshift tables, can I access the table defined in Glue data catalog?

What will be the create external table query to reference the table definition in Glue catalog?

Answer (score 11):

From AWS ([Creating External Schemas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-schemas.html)),

```
create external schema athena_schema from data catalog 
database 'sampledb' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MySpectrumRole' 
region 'us-east-2';
```

This creates a schema `athena_schema` that points to the `sampledb` database in Athena / Glue.

You need to grant appropriate access to the IAM role you specify: the Redshift cluster needs to be able to assume the role, and the role needs access to Glue.